# Check whether PHPUnit is currently running

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need a way to check whether PHPUnit is currently running. I cannot modify my xml file in order to add a custom variable. Does PHPUnit sets any global variable on execution?

I tried checking for

> PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL

but false is returned from

```
defined('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL')
```

Comment: You can check whether PHP is running in CLI mode with `PHP_SAPI`, and then `$argv[0]` to see the invoked script for a hint of PHPUnit.

Comment: Just tried that, still not working

Answer (score 1):

PhpUnit 9.5 creates `$GLOBALS['phpunit_version']`, so you can do stuff like:

```
if ( ! array_key_exists( 'phpunit_version', $GLOBALS ) ) {
    // Code that should not run during tests.
}
```

If that changes in a future version, you can check `$GLOBALS` by running something like this in [`setUpBeforeClass`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html)

```
foreach( $GLOBALS as $key => $value ) {
    if ( false !== stripos( $key, 'phpunit' ) ) {
        var_dump( $key );
    }
}
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit what you're asking for, if inspecting `$_SERVER['argv']` does not do it for you already, there is always [`get_declared_classes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) or [`get_defined_constants()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) you can use for inspection of the the current runtime state (if not `$GLOBALS`), but you might equally not be able to build on top of that.

If you're specifically concerned about the runner, the class has the version (the name of the class may differ with the Phpunit version you have in use, also how to access it statically):

- `PHPUnit_Runner_Version::VERSION` - Phpunit Test-Runner version as class constant, e.g. `'3.7.38'`.
- `PHPUnit\Runner\Version::id()` - Phpunit Test-Runner version as public static class method, e.g. `'9.5.28'`.

Location and public access of the version does differ across Phpunit versions, but as you have access to the sources, it is normally easy to locate.